# React router location becomes undefined when route changes

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that has a function to use `history.goBack()`. I also use `location.state` in the template of that component. When I trigger the `goBack()`, i get an error that says location is undefined. The location is not needed anymore, because we are switching to a component that doesnt use `location`

```
const ProfilePage = () => {
const location = useLocation()
const history = useHistory()
const goBack = () => {
    history.goBack();
}
return (
    <IonPage>
        <IonHeader>
            <IonToolbar>
                <IonIcon icon={arrowBackCircle} size={"large"} onClick={goBack}/>
            </IonToolbar>
        </IonHeader>
        <IonContent>
            <IonCard>
                <IonCardHeader>
                    <IonCardSubtitle>{location.state.data.contactPerson}</IonCardSubtitle>
                   
                </IonCardHeader>
                <IonCardContent><div><img src={location.state.data.image}/></div></IonCardContent>
                
            </IonCard>

        </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
);
};

export default ProfilePage
```

[image]

Comment: It does not say that `location` is undefined, it says that `location.state` is undefined. You just need to check that the the property exists before trying to access deeply nested values.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, didn't notice. In any case, when I access the values and am using the component, the data shows. Its just when im trying to route away from the component does the error happen @BrianThompson